# SharpDX memory fragmentation

Tags: c#, memory, directx-9, sharpdx, memory-fragmentation

I am working on a .NET 3.5 application which uses SharpDX to render tiled 2D images.

Textures (Texture2D) are loaded into a cache on-demand, and are created in the managed pool.

Textures are disposed of when no longer required, and I have verified that Dispose() is called correctly. SharpDX object tracking indicates that there are no textures being finalized.

The issue is that large amounts of unmanaged heap memory used by the textures continues to be reserved after disposal. This memory is reused when loading a new texture, so memory is not being leaked.

However, another part of the application also requires significant chunks of memory to process new images. Because these heaps are still present, even though the textures have been disposed, there is not enough contiguous memory to load another image (can be hundreds of MB).

If I allocate unmanaged meory using `AllocHGlobal`, the resulting 
heap memory completely vanishes again after calling `FreeHGlobal`.

[image: Fragmentation]

VMMap shows the unmanaged heap (red) after heavy usage of the application.

[image: Unmanaged Heap]

We can see here that unmanaged heap accounts for ~380MB, even though only ~20MB is actually committed at this point.

Long term, the application is being ported to 64-bit. However, this is not trivial due to unmanaged dependencies. Also, not all users are on 64-bit machines.

**EDIT:** I've put together a demonstration of the issue - create a WinForms application and install SharpDX 2.6.3 via Nuget.

**Form1.cs:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SharpDX.Direct3D9;

namespace SharpDXRepro {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        private readonly SharpDXRenderer renderer;
        private readonly List<Texture> textures = new List<Texture>();

        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();

            renderer = new SharpDXRenderer(this);

            Debugger.Break(); // Check VMMap here

            LoadTextures();

            Debugger.Break(); // Check VMMap here

            DisposeAllTextures();

            Debugger.Break(); // Check VMMap here

            renderer.Dispose();

            Debugger.Break(); // Check VMMap here
        }

        private void LoadTextures() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                textures.Add(renderer.LoadTextureFromFile(@"D:\Image256x256.jpg"));
            }
        }

        private void DisposeAllTextures() {
            foreach (var texture in textures.ToArray()) {
                texture.Dispose();
                textures.Remove(texture);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SharpDXRenderer.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SharpDX.Direct3D9;

namespace SharpDXRepro {
    public class SharpDXRenderer : IDisposable {
        private readonly Control parentControl;

        private Direct3D direct3d;
        private Device device;
        private DeviceType deviceType = DeviceType.Hardware;
        private PresentParameters presentParameters;
        private CreateFlags createFlags = CreateFlags.HardwareVertexProcessing | CreateFlags.Multithreaded;

        public SharpDXRenderer(Control parentControl) {
            this.parentControl = parentControl;

            InitialiseDevice();
        }

        public void InitialiseDevice() {
            direct3d = new Direct3D();
            AdapterInformation defaultAdapter = direct3d.Adapters.First();

            presentParameters = new PresentParameters {
                Windowed = true,
                EnableAutoDepthStencil = true,
                AutoDepthStencilFormat = Format.D16,
                SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard,
                PresentationInterval = PresentInterval.One,
                BackBufferWidth = parentControl.ClientSize.Width,
                BackBufferHeight = parentControl.ClientSize.Height,
                BackBufferCount = 1,
                BackBufferFormat = defaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Format,
            };

            device = new Device(direct3d, direct3d.Adapters[0].Adapter, deviceType,
                parentControl.Handle, createFlags, presentParameters);
        }

        public Texture LoadTextureFromFile(string filename) {
            using (var stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
                return Texture.FromStream(device, stream, 0, 0, 1, Usage.None, Format.Unknown, Pool.Managed, Filter.Point, Filter.None, 0);
            }
        }

        public void Dispose() {
            if (device != null) {
                device.Dispose();
                device = null;
            }

            if (direct3d != null) {
                direct3d.Dispose();
                direct3d = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My question therefore is - (how) can I reclaim the memory consumed by these unmanaged heaps after the textures have been disposed?

Comment: How are you loading the textures?

Comment: `Texture texture = Texture.FromStream(device, stream, 0, 0, 1,
                    Usage.None, Format.Unknown, Pool.Managed, Filter.Point, Filter.None, 0);`

Where stream is currently always a MemoryStream.

Comment: I've added a simplified code sample which reproduces the issue.

Comment: This probably will not make you happy, but it doesn't reproduce for me. I'm using the latest pre-lease version of SharpDX, and I'm on Windows 7 (with nVidia Quadro). As soon as `DisposeAllTextures` executes, all the unmanaged VM is gone. Also, I run the code outside of the debugger - that might also make a difference.

Comment: Any response makes me happy at the moment! Thanks for trying it out. I'm on Windows 8.1 with a Quadro NVS 315. I can reproduce with release build outside of debugger. The actual application does the same thing on Windows 7, with various other Quadro cards. So perhaps SharpDX is favourite here - did you use 3.0.0-alpha02? If so, I'll try using it on my machine.

Comment: Yeah, 3.0.0-alpha02. For some reason, 2.6.3 doesn't work at all for me. Other than that, perhaps the exact kind of data makes a difference as well? I've used a PNG instead of JPG.

Comment: Just rebuilt sample with SharpDX 3.0.0-alpha02, can still reproduce. Heap size after everything is disposed is 375,600K - only 3300K committed though. Just to check - did you build targeting x86? For what it's worth, my nVidia drivers are v327.39.

Comment: Good point, but it works fine for me on x86 as well. The commit is never further away from size than about 3 MiB. The file I'm trying takes about 20 MiB of the heap per (which is about the size of a heap block for me - two do not fit in the same block). Using a smaller file doesn't change anything, though (apart from the size of the heap block, of course). How many blocks does your heap have when it "breaks"? How big are those? The unmanaged heap has different behaviour based on the amount of memory you request.

Comment: I'm starting to think you're allocating so small pieces of memory at once, that the heap manager uses the "power of two" approach - expanding the heap to twice the size all the time. This cannot be released as long as parts of the heap block are still in use.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure that's the problem now. If you're allocating less than a certain amount of memory at a time, it's allocated on the small-object-heap, basically - a collection of *shared* heap blocks. The problem is that the block can only be released when it no longer has any references - due to some tiny thing remaining, the block cannot be reclaimed. When you go through the textures again, you fill up all the blocks already allocated, and the "pinned" handle will be created in another one, preventing *that one* from being released. This continues until your VM is fragmented to death.

Comment: The file I'm using is a 256x256 JPEG, which by my reckoning is about 256KiB on a 32-bit texture (I'm assuming DirectX doesn't keep the JPEG header). I am left with 478 blocks after everything is disposed. Almost every address listed under heap 1 is 16MiB and contains 10 - 20 blocks (a couple of outliers up to 60 blocks).

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense! I'm not sure what should be left over in those blocks after all textures, device and D3D instance have been disposed though - any ideas?

Comment: Yeah. So most of your blocks are composed of 4 kiB of committed memory, followed by 252 kiB of reserved memory not big enough to allocate the bitmap, right? I'm trying to trace the source of that allocation now (debugging CLR code with VMMap is a bit tricky :D). It might be some marshalling helper or file buffer or something like that.

Comment: Picking a few at random - 4K committed followed by 504K reserved, then 4K committed followed by 344K reserved. So pretty much, yep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the memory that's giving the issues is allocated by the nVidia driver. As far as I can tell, all the deallocation methods are properly called, so this might be a bug in the drivers. Looking around the internet shows some issues that seem related to this, though it's nothing serious enough to be worth referencing. I can't test this on an ATi card (I haven't seen one in like ten years :D).

So it seems like your options are:

- Make sure your textures are big enough to never be allocated on the "shared" heaps. This allows the memory leak to proceed much slower - although it's still unreleased memory, it's not going to cause memory fragmentation anywhere near as serious as you're experiencing. You're talking about drawing tiles - this has historically been done with tilesets, which give you a lot better handling (though they also have drawbacks). In my tests, simply avoiding tiny textures all but eliminated the problem - it's hard to tell if it's just hidden or completely gone (both are quite possible).
- Handle your processing in a separate process. Your main application would launch the other process whenever needed, and the memory will be properly reclaimed when the helper process exits. Of course, this only makes sense if you're writing some processing application - if you're making something that actually displays the textures, this isn't going to help (or at least it's going to be really tricky to setup).
- Do not dispose of the textures. `Managed` texture pool handles paging the texture to and from the device for you, and it even allows you to use priorities etc., as well as flushing the whole on-device (managed) memory. This means that the textures will remain in your process memory, but it seems that you'll still get better memory usage than with your current approach :)
- Possibly, the problems might be related to e.g. DirectX 9 contexts only. You might want to test with one of the newer interfaces, like DX10 or DXGI. This doesn't necessarily limit you to DX10+ GPUs - but you will lose support for Windows XP (which isn't supported anymore anyway).

Comment: I'm not sure what you used to arrive at the conclusion of the nVidia driver - but DebugDiag gives nvd3dum!QueryOglResource a 97% chance of leaking, so I think you're probably right. I don't have an ATI card to hand, but will see what I can find.

Comment: Also, I tested 512x512 textures, very little heap is left over at the end, as you said. Thank you very much for your assistance, it's been very educational!

Comment: @BenOwen It's been a lot of fun. Although it's frustrating that in the end, the answer still seems to be "Too bad, it's broken. Try to avoid the sharp edges." :D

Comment: Found a machine with an old ATI FireGL in it, unfortunately can still reproduce on it. Possible that the ATI driver is also broken, I guess, but seems like the issue must be elsewhere.

Comment: @BenOwen One interesting thing is that it seems that the leak isn't deterministic - the amount of leaked memory doesn't seem to be linear with respect to the amount of textures (or their total size). This might imply that the problem occurs because of some faulty access to shared memory. The fact that the problem seems to diminish (or even go away entirely) might simply be a side-effect of slowing down the creation / disposal of textures. It's really hard to tell anything useful.